# OWASP/ZAP dangling when trying to scan

Tags: owasp, zap

I am trying out OWASP/ZAP to see if it is something we can use for our project, but I cannot make it work I don't know what I am doing wrong and the documentation really does not help. What I am trying is to run a scan on my api running in a docker container locally on my windows machine so I run the command:
`docker run -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t http://172.21.0.2:8080/swagger.json -g gen.conf -r testreport.html` the ip `172.21.0.2` is the IPAddress of my api container even tried with `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`

but it just hangs in the following log message:

```
_XSERVTransmkdir: ERROR: euid != 0,directory /tmp/.X11-unix will not be created.
Feb 14, 2019 1:43:31 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
INFO: Created user preferences directory.
```

Nothing happens and my zap docker container is in a unhealthy state, after some time it just crashes and ends up with a bunch of NullPointerExceptions. Is zap docker only working for linux, something specifically I need to do when running it on a windows machine? I don't get why this is not working even when I am following specifically the guideline in https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Docker

**Edit 1**
My latest try where I am trying to target my host ip address directly and the port that I am exposing my api to gives me the following error:

```
_XSERVTransmkdir: ERROR: euid != 0,directory /tmp/.X11-unix will not be created.
Feb 14, 2019 2:12:07 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
INFO: Created user preferences directory.
Total of 3 URLs
ERROR Permission denied
2019-02-14 14:12:57,116 I/O error(13): Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/zap/zap-baseline.py", line 347, in main
    with open(base_dir + generate, 'w') as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/zap/wrk/gen.conf'
Found Java version 1.8.0_151
Available memory: 3928 MB
Setting jvm heap size: -Xmx982m
213 [main] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.DaemonBootstrap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key error here is:

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/zap/wrk/gen.conf'

This means that the script cannot write to the gen.conf file that you have mounted on /zap/wrk

Do you have write access to the cwd when its not mounted?

Comment: Yeah I was aware of that but thanks. I am using cygwin on Windows, so I just have to figure out how to enable write access to my pwd for the docker container, but that might be more of a specific `docker for windows` question, I have had some other problems before with mounting volumes in Windows, anyway sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Its ok, dont be afraid top ask questions :)

Answer (score 5):

When you run docker with: docker run -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw ... 
you are mapping the /zap/wrk/ directory in the docker image to the current working directory (cwd) of the machine in which you are running docker.

I think the problem is that your current user doesn't have write access to the cwd.

Try below command, hope it resolves issue.

$docker run --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw --rm -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t https://your_url -g gen.conf -r testreport.html

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is, if you use -r parameter, zap will attempt to generate the file report.html at location `/zap/wrk/`. In order to make this work, we have to mount a directory to this location `/zap/wrk`.

But when you do so, it is important that the zap container is able to perform the write operations on the mounted directory.

So, below is the working solution using gitlab ci yml. I started with this approach of using `image: owasp/zap2docker-stable` however then had to go to the vanilla docker commands to execute it.

```
  test_site:
          stage: test
          image: docker:latest
          script:
          # The folder zap-reports created locally will be mounted to owasp/zap2docker docker container,
          # On execution it will generate the reports in this folder. Current user is passed so reports can be generated"
            - mkdir zap-reports
            - cd zap-reports
            - docker pull owasp/zap2docker-stable:latest || echo
            - docker run  --name zap-container --rm -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk -u $(id -u ${USER}):$(id -g ${USER}) owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t "https://example.com" -r report.html
          artifacts:
            when: always
            paths:
              - zap-reports
          allow_failure: true
```

So the trick in the above code is

1. Mount local directory **zap-reports to /zap/wrk** as in `$(pwd):/zap/wrk`
2. Pass the current user and group on the host machine to the docker container so the process is using the same user / group. This allows writing of reports on the directory mounted from local host. This is done by `-u $(id -u ${USER}):$(id -g ${USER})`

Below is the working code with `image: owasp/zap2docker-stable`

```
 test_site:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  stage: test
  image:
    name: owasp/zap2docker-stable:latest
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p /zap/wrk
  script:
    - zap-baseline.py -t "https://example.com" -g gen.conf -I -r testreport.html
    - cp /zap/wrk/testreport.html testreport.html
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - zap.out
      - testreport.html
```

Answer (score 0):

A file based option has been specified but the directory '/zap/wrk' is not mounted

Also make sure it is `$(pwd):/zap/wrk` and not `$(pwd):/zap/wrk/`

Can also

```bash
docker run  --rm -v C:\git\ZAP-demo/content:/zap/wrk:rw -it owasp/zap2docker-weekly
```

and then interactively `cd` to `/zap/wrk` and create files and see if file is created on host and can write to it.

OR

```bash
docker run  --user 0:0 --rm -v C:\git\ZAP-demo/content:/zap/wrk:rw  -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly /bin/sh -c  "id; cd /zap/wrk;pwd; echo hi>test.txt"
```

Notice I am running as root, try to take the `--user` off and see what happens